# How do I make these cards align with equal gap?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using css grids to make some divs align. As seen in the picture provided, the cards have an uneven gap between them. I don't want to use padding or position translate to align them because the resolutions sizes will differ from device to device and it will look all jumbled.

[image: Here is the picture]

HTML:

```
<div class= "column">   <!--this column has been placed so that it can include a number of div boxes that 
carries the solutions for the website.  -->

  <div class="card card1">
    <h5>breathing tool</h5>
    
    <a href="breathing-tool.html">
      <ol> 
        <li> Breathing helps reduce anxiousness. </li>
         <li> This mini programme is developed to help with rhytmic breathing. </li>
            
      
        </ol>
    </a>
    </div> 


    <div class="card card2">
      <h5>Pink meditation room</h5>
      
          <a href="pink-meditation.html"><p> This is the breathing tool and will help with the clamness of the users</p></a>
    </div> 

       
      

      <div class="card card3">
        <h5> Quote dispenser</h5>
 <a href="quote-generator.html"><p> This is the breathing tool and will help with the clamness of the users</p></a>
        
        </div> 


          
</div> <!--this is the closing tag of "column"-->
```

CSS:

```
column{
display: grid;                               
height: auto;
width: auto;
grid-template-columns: repeat(2,4fr);
/*the colums numbers have been replaced with a repeat of 2 columns with the specified size of 4fractions*/
grid-template-rows: 2.5fr 2.5fr 2.5fr 2.5fr 2.5fr;
background-color: bisque;
grid-template-areas:
"card1 card1 card2 card2 card3 card3";

/* The display grid here works by making the card divs 
align properly like I need them to. This will make 
space for writng and describing each of the provided
solutions without a disorientation.*/
}


.card{                                                                 
width: 250px;
height: 350px;
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 15px;
box-sizing: border-box;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 30px 70px;
background-image: url(images/pink2.png);
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
transition: transform 0.5s;
```

Comment: Instead of a grid, use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/): https://jsfiddle.net/ruoL1hw5/

Comment: Have you provided the whole code? I tried to copy-paste into CodePen and it didnt give complete styling as shown in the image. Also, try to make it a code snippet so viewers can run it right away in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flexbox` instead of `grid`

Remove all the `grid` in `.column` and replace them with these:

```
    display: flex; /* adding flex */
    justify-content: space-around; /* Positioning them with spaces */
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* Wrapping Elements when page is small */
```

I also added a border to show the elements, you can remove it.

Don't forget to run the code snippet and press full page to see the full result

---

### This would be your final code:

```css
.column{
display: flex; /* adding flex */
justify-content: space-around; /* Positioning them with spaces */
flex-wrap: wrap; /* Wrapping Elements when page is small */
height: auto;
width: auto;
background-color: bisque;
}

.card{                                                                 
width: 250px;
height: 350px;
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 15px;
box-sizing: border-box;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 30px 70px;
background-image: url(images/pink2.png);
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
transition: transform 0.5s;

/* You can remove this: */
border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class= "column">   <!--this column has been placed so that it can include a number of div boxes that 
carries the solutions for the website.  -->

  <div class="card card1">
    <h5>breathing tool</h5>
    
    <a href="breathing-tool.html">
      <ol> 
        <li> Breathing helps reduce anxiousness. </li>
         <li> This mini programme is developed to help with rhytmic breathing. </li>
            
      
        </ol>
    </a>
    </div> 


    <div class="card card2">
      <h5>Pink meditation room</h5>
      
          <a href="pink-meditation.html"><p> This is the breathing tool and will help with the clamness of the users</p></a>
    </div> 

       
      

      <div class="card card3">
        <h5> Quote dispenser</h5>
 <a href="quote-generator.html"><p> This is the breathing tool and will help with the clamness of the users</p></a>
        
        </div> 


          
</div> <!--this is the closing tag of "column"-->
```

Comment: Hello, thankyou so much for helping me out. it runs perfectly, the only problem is that with grids I could position the boxes to be vertical when the screen size reduces to lets say 600px. I am not sure if I could use this to make it vertically align for smaller resolutions.

Comment: Hi @heleni, of course you can do it with flex too. Just add `flex-direction: column;` and if you want to center it then also add `align-items: center;` to the `.column` class . The `align-items: center;` is based on the `flex-direction` . If it's `flex-direction: column;` then you can vertically align it with `align-items: center;`. But if the `flex-direction` is `row` then you can vertically align it with `justify-content: center;` .  Hope i could help :) Sorry for replying a bit late :)